# Dissect an id with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, variables

How would I go about disecting an id, turning this `id="type=2owner=6page=1"` into this:

```
var type = "2"; // or what ever is after type= but before owner=
var owner = "6"; // or what ever is after owner= but before page=
var page = "1"; // or what ever is after page=
```

The numbers won't always be the same or single digit.

Comment: will it always be a number? How do you know to stop after the 2 and that `owner` is not part of `pr-type`?

Comment: why not use attributes like "data-type" to store the values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can* accomplish what you're trying to do, but you should almost certainly be using data attributes instead.

Instead of packing data into your `id` attribute, use separate `data-` attributes:

```
<div id="my-div" data-type="2" data-owner="6" data-page="1" />
```

jQuery gives you a very easy syntax for accessing an element's data attributes:

```
$('#my-div').data('type');  // "2"
$('#my-div').data('owner'); // "6"
$('#my-div').data('page');  // "1"
```

Or, for changing/adding new data attributes:

```
$('#my-div').data("name", "bob"); // <div .... data-name="bob" />
```

---

If you're unable to add data attributes to your markup (if, for example, you're only consuming the HTML and not generating it) you can use regular expressions to pull the `id` attribute apart:

```
var id = "type=2owner=6page=1";

id.match(/type=(\d+)/);  // ["type=1", "1"]
id.match(/owner=(\d+)/); // ["owner=6", "6"]
id.match(/page=(\d+)/);  // ["page=2", "2"]
```

Any of the above will return a two element array, where the second element is the digit in question.

Comment: Thanks. This method is way better, I wasn't away such a thing existed.

Answer (score 1):

```
var id = document.getElementById(...).getAttribute("id").split(/=/g);
var type = id[1];
var owner = id[3];
var page = id[5];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something more scalable. This will create a nice object with all your keywords or terms and their values and it's easily extendable with more terms.

```
var id = 'type=2owner=6page=1'
var terms = ['type', 'owner', 'page']
var results = {}

for (var i = 0, n = terms.length, m, re; i < n; i++) {
  m = terms[i]
  re = new RegExp(m + '=(\\d+)', 'i')
  results[m] = re.exec(id)[1]
}

console.log(results) // { type: 2, owner: 6, page: 1 }
```